# Automatic OTP verification in iOS: OTP not appearing on the keyboard toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, one-time-password

I am trying to implement automatic OTP verification in my Xcode project. I have written the following code, but the OTP value doesn't appear on the keyboard toolbar as expected. I have also added the "Autofill Credential Provider" under the Xcode Capability section. My testing device is running on iOS 16, and I have set the keyboard type under the text input trait to "Number Pad." I have also tried with the `default` keyboard type, but it didn't work either.
AutoFill Password is enabled on my device settings

Here is the code snippet I have used:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        otp1.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
        otp2.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
        otp3.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
        otp4.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
    }

    otp1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEdited), for: .editingChanged)
    otp2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEdited), for: .editingChanged)
    otp3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEdited), for: .editingChanged)
    otp4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEdited), for: .editingChanged)
    otp1.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

And I defined didEdited method in viewController

```
@objc func didEdited(textField: UITextField) {
    let text = textField.text

    if text?.count == 1 {
        switch textField {
        case otp1:
            otp2.becomeFirstResponder()
        case otp2:
            otp3.becomeFirstResponder()
        case otp3:
            otp4.becomeFirstResponder()
        case otp4:
            otp4.resignFirstResponder()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    if text?.count == 0 {
        switch textField {
        case otp1:
            otp1.becomeFirstResponder()
        case otp2:
            otp2.text = ""
            otp1.becomeFirstResponder()
        case otp3:
            otp3.text = ""
            otp2.becomeFirstResponder()
        case otp4:
            otp4.text = ""
            otp3.becomeFirstResponder()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The OTP message format I am receiving is as follows: "Your OTP to register/access [App Name] is 1654".

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play around with your SMS text. iOS does recognise OTP codes only if it matched with some format.

First of all be sure that `Autofill passwords` is turned on in your settings.

Secondary, play with sms text. Make sure otp message phrase has "code" or "passcode" or "password" and message is copyable.

Examples, that work:

1. Some text about and SMS-code: 12345 - correct
2. Some text about and Your code: 1234 - correct
3. Some text about and SMS-code: 12345 correct
4. Some text about and Your password: 1234 correct

Also, take care about localisations. If your device has different localisation, that comes in sms - autofill can fail.
And security code only work with System keyboard. Avoid using custom keyboard.